# Spark with Parquet - dealing with schema mismatches

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, data-transform

I have a bunch of Parquet files on S3 that I am trying to read with Spark. The parquet files have schema mismatches for one or more columns. One of the columns is `category_id`. Some of the files have it stored as a String while the others have it stored as an Int.

I tried using `mergeschema` option and it didn't work. I tried casting the column in the `dataframe` I also tried converting the `dataframe` to an `rdd` and then do a `map` operation but with both attempts, I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file  Column: [category_id], Expected: string, Found: INT32
```

what's the best way to deal with this scenario? I am trying to explore reading the parquet files as binary and then parse the rows and columns, will that work?